# GeoServer SQL VIEW

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, javascript

I am trying to add layer through SQL VIEW GeoServer.

Everything is fine just, GeoServer is not able to take some chars correctly.

When name parameter includes dash "-" character, the WMS not able to show layer on map.

Query:  `select * from public."MyLayer" where name like '%%name%'`

In PostgreSQL, the query is working, but in SQL, view it does not show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent SQL injection attacks there is a validation regular expression that is used to check if a parameter is acceptable. By default this is `^[\w\d\s]+$` which means that only "word characters (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`)", digits and white space are allowed. So if your name contains a `-` it is rejected.

You need to add `-` into the validation check (this is a little tricky because `-` is a special character) so change it to something like `^[-\w\d\s]+$`